# Scala hierarchy decomposition and type parameters

Tags: oop, scala, pattern-matching, class-hierarchy

I have the following class hierarchy.

```
sealed trait Foo {
  val a: String 
}
case class Bar1(a: String) extends Foo
case class Bar2(a: String) extends Foo
```

Now I want to add a convenient method to modify the field `a`. I need this method to be accessible in the super type `Foo` and I want to use the `.copy` method of the case class (because I actually have a lot more fields and it is painful to use the constructor). My first attempt was to use pattern matching :

```
sealed trait Foo {
  val a: String
  def withField(b: String) = this match {
    case b1: Bar1 => b1.copy(a = b)
    case b2: Bar2 => b2.copy(a = b)
  }
}
```

Now I would also like my `withField` method to return an instance type of the caller, `B1` if the method is called by an instance of type `B1`, `B2` if the method is called by an instance of type `B2` and `Foo` if this is all I know. So I thought to myself I might be able to parametrized the method `withField`to serve this purpose. Something like:

```
sealed trait Foo {
  val a: String
  def withField[A <: Foo](b: String) = this match {
    case b1: Bar1 => b1.copy(a = b)
    case b2: Bar2 => b2.copy(a = b)
  }
}
```

but I don't manage to parametried `withField` with the type of `this`.

Am I getting completely wrong here ? Should I use a different pattern maybe using `override` modifier ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I getting completely wrong here ? Should I use a different pattern maybe using override modifier ?

Yes. There are two alternatives:

```
sealed trait Foo {
  val a: String
  def withField(b: String): Foo
}

case class Bar1(a: String) extends Foo {
  // return types are covariant, and Bar1 is subtype of Foo,
  // so this is legal
  def withField(b: String): Bar1 = ...
}
```

or

```
sealed trait Foo[ThisType <: Foo[ThisType]] {
  val a: String
  def withField(b: String): ThisType
}

case class Bar1(a: String) extends Foo[Bar1] {
  def withField(b: String): Bar1 = ...
}
```

Note the second is more complex, and should only be used if you actually need it.

EDIT to answer Christian's question:

```
sealed trait Foo {
  type ThisType <: Foo
  def withField(b: String): ThisType = (this match {
    case b1: Bar1 => b1.copy(a = b)
    ...
  }).asInstanceOf[ThisType]
}

case class Bar1(a: String) extends Foo {
  type ThisType = Bar1
}
```

I don't like it: it needs a cast, actually using it would require dependent method types, and I wouldn't be surprised if it broke down in practice (e.g. because the compiler can't prove `foo.ThisType` and `foo.withField("a").ThisType` are the same).

Comment: One question remains for me: is it possible to implement withField in the trait and returning there the right type (like Benoit tried to do)?

Comment: @Christian See the edit. I wouldn't use it, unless absolutely required for some reason.

Comment: yes I think the second method is too complex. Ok so I guess if I want to return instance of Bar1 and Bar2, I can't abstract `withField` in the parent class